# Laravel Validation with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, laravel-4

I am running jQuery Autocomplete with a Laravel form field.

It grabs data from my db

```
Specialty Area Examples: Real Estate, Mortgage Lenders, Renovation, Buyer's Agent, Listing Agent, Relocation, Short-Sale, Consulting, Local Experts, Refinancing, Architecture, Home Building, Carpentry, Electrical, Engineering, Interior Design, Landscaping, Painting, Plumbing, Appraisal, Commercial Property, Insurance, Legal, Conveyancing,
```

Users can type in one of the examples and the autocomplete will complete the rest in the field.

I want to limit the user to being allowed to input a maximum of 4 Specialty Area Examples into the form field.  So a user can type in for example:

Real Estate, Short-Sale, Consulting, Local Experts

After that the user should not be allowed to input more data.

I'm lost as to how to achieve this with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to use the Jquery Autocomplete:

1. You Must be using the HTML code for Autocomplete
2. Do Ajax POST to get the Data from your server side.
3. Your Jquery code should be something like this:

   ```
   var data=[ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl" ];   

   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       //source: data
       source: function(request, response) {
           var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, request.term);
           response(results.slice(0, 2));
       }
   });
   ```

where 'data' is an array containing List of values in string format.
You can push the data into that using the response you will get from `AJAX post`
and that will be used as a Suorce.

use this link for your Better Reference::
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/2QRML/1/

For getting the Autocomplete valu on Minimum length string typed hav a look to this::
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/2QRML/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtBox").keypress(function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (input.split(',').length > 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y6eQF/